# How to display filters in tensorboard

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning, tensorboard

I have a simple MNIST model from the tensorflow tutorial. I want to see how the first convolutional layer's filters changes with time. When I use tf.summary.image, only one of the steps is displayed, and the rest is ignored. Is there any way to work this around?

Answer (score 1):

TF does not have videos, but you can generate image at each step, save them in some directory and then [create a video from them](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34975972/1090562).