# Artist animation from several plots from for loop in python

Tags: python, animation

I'm currently trying to prepare an artist animation. Using a for loop, I have generated ~50 individual plots, which I now want to be shown within an animation one after the other (like in a slide show). Thus, all the pictures are already there. Is there a straight forward way to just "show" them one after the other?

Thank you a lot! :)

Comment: Check out [ffmpeg](https://www.ffmpeg.org/), its a command line tool which is feature rich and does exactly that. See this [ffmpeg python package](https://github.com/kkroening/ffmpeg-python) to allow you to use it within your python script.

Comment: Multiple options. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34975972/how-can-i-make-a-video-from-array-of-images-in-matplotlib https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44947505/how-to-make-a-movie-out-of-images-in-python